# Is there is anyone how make a four-column dynamic table by using HTML, CSS and JavaScript in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there is anyone how make a four-column table by using HTML CSS Javascript in Angular? The table has a search, edit and delete button Data is store on browser only.

Comment: Why didn't use a [Angular Material table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:table` to [create CSS table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display):

```css
.fooGrid
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fooGrid">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```